# Code runs in spyder but not in online test?

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to solve a problem in Hackerrank, the code runs fine in Spyder, but throws a runtime error when I run it in their online testing window.

```
N = int(raw_input())
myDict = {} 

for i in range (N) :
    element = raw_input().split()
    myDict[element[0]]=element[1]

queries = []

while True:
    query = map(str,raw_input().split())
    queries.append(query)

for j in range(len(queries)):
    NF = True 
    for name in myDict:    
        if queries[j][0] == name : 
            print name + '=' + myDict[name]
            NF = False 
    if (NF):
        print 'Not found'
```

This code runs fine and passes the test case (which is input from the keyboard in Spyder). When I try to run it against the following test case in Hackerrank's online testing window, on the following inputs:

```
3
sam 99912222
tom 11122222
harry 12299933
sam
edward
harry
```

I get a runtime error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "solution.py", line 13, in <module>
query = map(str,raw_input().split())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I think something is wrong with the way it is reading the final line of the input, but I don't know to fix it.

Comment: Ay ay. Raw Input?

Comment: @AllDani.com not following?

Comment: How can raw input work? If I run a file with raw input in it on my terminal (Mac) it works, but in Sublime it'll throw a EOF. That's input for you :)

Comment: But: http://pythontutor.com allows input testing!

Comment: where is link to description of this task ? Maybe you have to use `try/except`. BTW: how can it work if you don't leave `while True:` loop ?

Comment: BTW: `raw_input().split()` gives list of strings so you don't need `map(str,...)`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples and discussion on using try/except to handle the error of there being no further input: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps/forum/comments/135546